# linq to entity update records to database

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is the update code I found:

```
using (TestDBEntities ctx = new TestDBEntities())
{
    //Get the specific employee from Database

    Emp e = (from e1 in ctx.Emp
         where e1.Name == "Test Employee"
         select e1).First();

    //Change the Employee Name in memory
    e.Name = "Changed Name";

    //Save to database
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now what I am doing is like this:

```
 using(CRNNSTestEntities crnnsupContext = new CRNNSTestEntities())
 {
     CPersonalInfo t = ((IQueryable<CPersonalInfo>)Cache["personquery"]).First();

     t.Tombstone.Address = Address1.Text;
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(crnnsupContext.SaveChanges()+"");
 };
```

which doesn't work. So my question is do I have to write something like `CPersonalInfo t = from t in ....`

Why doesn't my method doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the entity `CPersonalInfo t` from your `crnnsupContext` and not from your `Cache`

Comment: does that mean every time I want to update the record, i have to run the search query first?

Comment: @pita - Yes, you need to retrieve the record from the context you are calling *SaveChanges()* with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach object to the context before.

More info how to use attach [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx)

Comment: Attaching object to the context before update / delete an object is a possibility described from Julia Lerman and  Rowan Miller (Program Manager for the ADO.NET Entity Framework team at Microsoft) in their "Programming Entity Framework: DbContext" at pag.47 - http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Entity-Framework-Julia-Lerman/dp/1449312969

Answer (score 0):

can you change this

```js
using (TestDBEntities ctx = new TestDBEntities())
{
    //Get the specific employee from Database

    Emp e = (from e1 in ctx.Emp
         where e1.Name == "Test Employee"
         select e1).First();

    //Change the Employee Name in memory
    e.Name = "Changed Name";

    //Save to database
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

into

```js
using (TestDBEntities ctx = new TestDBEntities())
{
    //Get the specific employee from Database

    Emp e = (from e1 in ctx.Emp
         where e1.Name == "Test Employee"
         select e1).First();
    var entity = ctx.Emp.Find(e);
    //Change the Employee Name in memory
    entity.Name = "Changed Name";

    //Save to database
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```